# Placeholder message not showing on expo app

Tags: expo, placeholder

Wondering why my placeholder docent show on the Expo app but shows on the web version. I tired finding a solution but don't know if this might be a bug within Expo....

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { 
  View, 
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router'
import styles from './welcome.style';
import { icons, SIZES } from '../../../constants';




const Welcome = () => {
  const router = useRouter();


  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>Welcome Anon,</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcomeMessage}>Find your perfect job</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <View style={styles.searchWrapper}>
          <TextInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          value=""
          onChange={() => {}}
          placeholder="Search for jobs"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `placeholderTextColor` prop for `TextInput`? I've noticed depending on your system theme (light / dark mode), the placeholder text color changes and it can be hard to read. So you could also try to change your mobile device's system theme and see if that was the culprit.

```
 <TextInput
    style={styles.searchInput}
    value=""
    onChange={() => {}}
    placeholder="Search for jobs"
    placeholderTextColor={'#bada55}
  />
```

[Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#placeholdertextcolor)